# Android: processing input in Timer to set in Textview

Tags: java, android

This native Braille app I am making has 6 different buttons that I would like to have every unique combination bring me different letters.

For example: I would like hitting button 1 to simple bring me the letter "A". Then hitting button 1 and button 2 continuously brings me the letter "C". I want every different button combination of these 6 buttons to bring me a seperate letter.

---

In `processInput()` I initiated `map` but when I tried clicking the buttons "The app automatically stopped"

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.keyboard);

      Window window = this.getWindow();
      window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
      window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
      window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

      // Init GUI
      txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMesssage);
      Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block1);
      Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block2);
      Button buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block3);
      Button buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block4);
      Button buttonFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block5);
      Button buttonSix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block6);



      // Attached Click Listener
      btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);

      buttonOne.setOnClickListener(this);
      buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
      buttonThree.setOnClickListener(this);
      buttonFour.setOnClickListener(this);
      buttonFive.setOnClickListener(this);
      buttonSix.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Timer processTimer = new Timer();

        processTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {    
                processInput();    
            }

            private void processInput() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                map.put(getString(R.id.block1), "A");
                map.put(getString(R.id.block1) + getString(R.id.block2), "C");

                map.get(R.id.block1);
                map.get(R.id.block1+R.id.block2);

            }
        }, 500); // Delay before processing. 

    processTimer.cancel();

    processTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {    
                processInput();    
            }

            private void processInput() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }
        }, 500);
}
```

XML Layout:

[image]

I can't seem to be getting it, I am getting errors in `Timer`.

Logcat error:

```
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677): Process: info.androidhive.speechtotext, PID: 20677
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was canceled
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677):    at java.util.Timer.scheduleImpl(Timer.java:558)
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677):    at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:456)
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677):    at info.androidhive.speechtotext.Braillekeyboard.onClick(Braillekeyboard.java:307)
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5225)
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21195)
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-12 21:43:09.764: E/AndroidRuntime(20677):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The original code:

```
Timer processTimer = new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {    processInput();    }
}, 500); // Delay before processing. 


processTimer.cancel();
processtimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {    processInput();    }
    }, 500);
```

Comment: Post the exception stacktrace from `logcat`

Comment: @KarsenGauss There you go, sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `schedule()` on a `cancelled` Timer. As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#cancel()), a cancelled Timer cannot be used again. You need a new instance.

Comment: Hello so what I shoud do ?

Comment: @pjforum why exactly do you need the second call to schedule()?

Comment: I edited, see the original code above. That's how it supposed to be, but I am getting some errors that's why I changed and added some codes on it. Was my correction was all wrong?

Comment: @pjforum the original code has the same problem. An instance of `processTimer` is created and `schedule()` is called on it. Then, `cancel()` is called, and another `schedule()` is call is made. That call will throw an exception. What the original code was meant to achieve?